# Reading deeply nested collection structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How could I get a bird's view of a returned collection regarding structure and collection types? I find it hard to iterate through a collection with so many objects that I cannot see the structure of the nesting.

When executing `Post.all.group_by {|post| post.category}` a nested `Hash` of some sort seem to be returned. `Post` belongs_to `Category`.

Comment: Group by returns a hash, mapping the group-by value to the objects that match that value.

You can get a "bird eye view" by pretty-printing your results, or by converting them to JSON and feeding it into a JSON validator, but you'll be much better served by figuring out how to read the regular debugging output Ruby and Rails give you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the awesome_print gem for great formatting.

https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use iteration all you have to do is this:

```
Category.all.each do |category|
    category.posts.each do |post|
        # your logic
    end
end
```